# How to get the mobile screen effect in videos?

Tags: effects, mobile

I am new to video editing and publishing and have recently started creating some content for my company. I am using Camtasia for the same which I have self learnt so high chances I may not know a lot of things about it.
Currently I am trying to make some video which I want to show as if they are in a mobile screen. An example of my requirement can be found at:

. I am planning to show some app features instead of whats shown in the video however, that mobile screen effect is something very close to what I need.
I would like to know how to achieve this? Can this be done in Camtasia or will I need some other tool for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need dedicated compositing software unless your NLE has some basic functionality built-in that allows you to do this. Here are some free or low-cost examples of compositing software:

- [After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html)
- [Fusion](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/fusion/)
- [HitFilm](https://hitfilm.com/)
- [Natron](https://natron.fr/) (GPL Open Source)